# xml2 library remove node: LOGICAL() can only be applied to a 'logical', not a 'list'

Tags: r, xml2

I am attempting to remove an  element from an html document using *xml2* library (1.3.2):

```
html <- "<html> <ul> <li>foo</li> </ul> </html>"
x <- read_html(html)
ul <- xml_find_first(x, ".//ul")
xml_remove(x, ul)
```

This results in:

```
Error in xml_remove.xml_node(x, ul) : 
  LOGICAL() can only be applied to a 'logical', not a 'list'
```

`ul` seems to be correct, of class *xml_node* with correct content.

Do I mess up something or does xml2 library have a problem?  The documentation is extremely sparse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
xml_remove(ul)
```

this is according to the [manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xml2/versions/1.3.2/topics/xml_replace) and seems to work.

```
> print(x)
{html_document}
<html>
[1] <body></body>
```

ul is gone.